# ProGuard makes apps not compile with "could not convert to dex bytecode with error 1"

Tags: java, android, apk, proguard, signing

I'm trying to export my Android app in Eclipse with the newest versions of Eclipse, the Android SDK, the ADT, and ProGuard. If I add the ProGuard cfg file to the default.properties file (no modifications to the cfg file) and try to export a signed apk, the exporter fails, saying that it couldn't convert to dex bytecode with error 1. Commenting out the ProGuard file makes it export just fine. I've tried starting Eclipse with the -clean flag, disabling obfuscation with the -dontobfuscate flag, cleaning the project many, many times, and fixing Android properties. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I had the acra library (jar) referenced and integrated, but have since removed it in an effort to fix this. It didn't help :( so, the only referenced library is the Android 2.1 library, added by the Create Project dialog. I've also tried deleting the project and re-grabbing it from my CVS, to no avail.

Comment: ProGuard does not do anything with Dex bytecode, so it seems something else is going on. Did you check Proguard's output to make sure it looks okay? Can you provide more information? Detailed error? Logs? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you are using the latest version of ProGuard (version 4.6 at this time of writing). If the latest version doesn't solve the problem, you can report an issue on ProGuard's bug tracker. In that case, you can work around the problem by reducing the number of optimization passes or by disabling optimization altogether.

Comment: I got the newest version from the ProGuard website and replaced the bundled one with it, to no avail. I'll try lowering optimization passes, but I'm not sure how that might help.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this answer actually fixed this problem for me (replacing the bundled ProGuard with v4.6).